# create google chrome extension like firefox addons

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created addon for firefox. I have to create same addon in google chrome(chrome extension).

In firefox I create widget according to pageurl. For other url I create another widget.(means I am creating widget dynamically)

In widget I am show a panel. In panel contentURL is dynamic Url created.

How to open server url in chrome popup. I want to create multiple popup instance for multiple pageurl.

Give suggestion for me.

Comment: What kind of widget/panel? If you want more than one widget+panel, forget it. If you need only one widget+panel, take a look at [`chrome.browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html).

Comment: I want to create multiple widget/panel.

Comment: You can modify the HTML of each page using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), so you could modify each page by injected CSS-styled panels into the webpage itself. However, this means your panels must be designed to stay consistent in spite of the styles that already exist on each page. I guarantee you will have a bad time implementing this functionality, but it is possible.

Comment: Hi @apsillers yes you are right. But I have to implement this. How my panels designed to stay consistent in spite of the styles that already exist on each page. Can you give me some idea.